# How to retrieve deleted printers

Tags: wireless, printing

So 2 of my network printers have been accidentally deleted. I've tried to re-add the printers, but Ubuntu wouldn't find them. I can only print via USB now. How can I re-add those printers wirelessly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a browser and type `localhost:631` This will access CUPS and then add the network printer via the Administration Tab. See http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/06/install-network-printers-cups-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/ for a better understanding.